# How do you name rods to fix several parallel metallical plates in mechanical devices?

Tags: terminology

In many mechanical devices, especial old ones, like clocks, the design is used, where two or more parallel planes fixed and all moving parts are placed in between.

In this case planes are fixed with metallic rods like this

[image]

What is the term for them?

Is this just "threaded rod" or "stud"?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_rod

---

Real world example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Spacers, spacer tubes, posts, mounting posts all can be used.

Answer (score 1):

A image search for [standoff+spacer](https://www.google.com/search?q=standoff+spacer&tbm=isch) results in the following.

[image]

The threaded hexagonal type are commonly used for PCB standoff and available from the major electronics suppliers.